# Поместить элемент в div bottom:0

Tags: html, css

Подскажите пожалуйста, как поместить текст прижать его к низу `div`

```html
<div style="width:200px;height:200px;border:1px solid;">
<div>
Нжиний текст
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Еще как вариант с абсолютным позиционированием внутри элемента с относительным:

```css
.external {
  width: 200px;
  height:200px;
  border:1px solid;
  
  position: relative; 
}

.internal {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="external">
  <div class="internal">
    Нжиний текст
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает.

Answer (score 1):

Вот примерно так

```css
.text{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: bottom;
width:200px;height:200px;border:1px solid;}

.text1 {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
    width:200px;height:200px;border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
<div>
Нжиний текст
</div>
</div>

<div class="text1">
<div>
Нжиний текст
</div>
</div>
```